# phpmyadmin export as gzip, bzip and zip gives network error

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, mysql

I try to export my database via phpmyadmin, I can export it without any compression but when I choose any sort of copression such as gzip, bzip or zip it ends up with network error (Chrome), the source file could not be read (firefox).

Comment: I bet it's CPanel's PMA, right? Does it happen if you install PMA in a subfolder?

Comment: well it's on my laptop localhost, using zend CE, even I updated phpmyadmin to the latest version, still no luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just changed zlib.output_compression = `Off` to `On` in my php.ini on my localhost and it fixed the problem